# Date field value timezone changing although site,field and user timezone is same

Tags: datetime

For view's footer I needed to compare field_last_date value with current date, no issues with comparison but when

- site's timezone is set to India(no option like Asia/Kolkata here am I
  missing something?)
- user's timezone is set to Asia/Kolkata: xxxxxx, xx xxxx xxxx - x:xxpm
  +0530
- field's timezone is set to **site's timezone** under *Time zone
  handling* settings

If field_last_date value is like 13/05/2014 - 12:00am and when it is outputted in view's footer with [field_last_date] it is showing 12/05/2014 - 6:30pm.But accoring to date api documentation

> Site's time zone - When entering data into the field, the data entered
>   is assumed to be in the site's time zone. When the data is saved to
>   the database, it is **converted to UTC**. When retrieved from the
>   database, the data is converted to the Site's time zone for anonymous
>   users or the **User's time zone** for logged in users when
>   User-configurable time zones is enabled.

Shouldn't it display according to *Time zone handling* settings as configured?.

**Update :**
View's display suite code in footer

```
$date_value = '[field_submission_end_date]';//token value of view field
$date_value = strtotime($date_value);
echo format_date($date_value,'medium');
echo format_date(time(),'medium');
```

After comment from Geoff I also tested by changing

```
site's default zone to Europe/Berlin
Admin' to Asia/Kolkata
testuser(non-admin) to America/New york
```

for all it is showing like
Mon, 12/05/2014 - 6:30pm
Thu, 26/06/2014 - 10:00am //current time
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it behave differently for anonymous users as it does for authenticated users? Does it actually perform timezone calculations, if for example you set the users timezone to something different, does it do the proper calculation, even if the result is off

Comment: @Geoff nope :( If end date value is like 13/05/2014 12:00AM then admin:Asia/Kolkata->12/05/2014 - 6:30pm, anonymous:site's zone->12/05/2014 - 6:30pm , testuser:US/New York->12/05/2014 - 6:30pm. For all users it is showing -5:30 of actual value.Anything else info reuired? will update question if any.

Comment: sorry for all the questions, but to better understand the problem - does it change if you change the system time zone, and does it change if you change the default country?

Comment: @Geoff no prob updated in question..